# Removing many to many Entity Framework (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Staffs` and `CLasses`.

```
public class Classes
    {
        public Classes()
        {
            Staffs = new List<Staffs>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }


        public virtual List<Staffs> Staffs { get; set; }
    } 

public class Staffs
    {
        public Staffs()
        {
            Classes = new List<Classes>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string IdentityNo { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Classes> Classes { get; set; }
    }
```

I can easily add Staff `Classes` like below

```
public bool AddStaffClasses(int staffId, int classId)
        {
            var staffs = context.Staffs.Where(x=>x.Id == staffId).SingleOrDefault();
            var classes = context.Classes.Where(x => x.Id == classId).SingleOrDefault();
            staffs.Classes.Add(classes);
            return context.SaveChanges() > 0 ? true : false;
        }
```

and always return **true**. But when I want to delete Staffs `CLasses` , it returns **true** unless I log out of the application. When I log out and log in again, it returns **false**

```
public bool RemoveStaffClasses(int staffId, int classId)
        {
            var classes = context.Classes.Where(x => x.Id == classId).SingleOrDefault();
            var staffs = context.Staffs.Where(x => x.Id == staffId).SingleOrDefault();
            staffs.Classes.Remove(classes);
            return context.SaveChanges() > 0 ? true : false;
        }
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'Logging out' should have no impact on the code you have shown.  If it does, then there it some other code that is affecting it.   If the remove doesn't affect a row it means that classes is null (because the SingleOrDefault doesn't find the class id), which is why 0 rows are changed by the SaveChanges.  Try (temporarily) changing the SingleOrDefault to Single, and see if you get an exception thrown.

Comment: I'm changing the SingleOrDefault to Single but nothing has changed. Because my classes doesnt return null. I founded problem, but I can't solve. My `Classes` class return like that. Id - 1, ClassName - "1 A" Staffs - Count = 0. also like my other `Staffs` class. Firstname - "Alex", Lastname etc. Classes - Count = 0. I think my problem is there

Comment: Check the database content after each call.

Comment: Can you post your 2 entity classes? (Class & Staff)

Comment: I checked the database, When I use add method database affected, but when I use delete method (after log out) database don't affected @GertArnold

Comment: @Neil Sure, I edited my post

Comment: Try `context.Classes.Include(c => c.Staffs)`.

Comment: Thank you bro. I try like this context.Classes.Include("Staffs"). It's woking. Thank you so much !